# How do the <script> tags generated by the `firebase init` work and are they compatible with a bundler like Browserify?

Tags: javascript, firebase, browserify

I'm trying to use Firebase with Browserify and certain tools in that territory have trouble with the firebase script tags. I'm guessing it's because the Browserify bundles don't include those resources (specifically Beefy, the hot-reload browserify local-server-helper), so those resources aren't found. Because I don't quite understand how those script tags work to begin with, I'm having trouble accommodating for their functionality.

I'm talking about these things:

```
    <!-- update the version number as needed -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.2/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.2/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.17.2/firebase-storage.js"></script>
    <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
    <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

The comments are somewhat helpful. My attention is pointed to the firebase 'init' source, which I'm guessing takes all the scripts above it to initialize the firebase keyword that is then used later in .js files.

However, in a bundled environment, should I be doing this a different way than the CLI sets it up?

Answer (score 1):

All of those script includes are only relevant if you're using Firebase products in web pages served by Firebase Hosting.  The `__` leading each path are reserved by Firebase Hosting for these types of scripts.

If you're not using Firebase Hosting, just remove them.

If you're using bundling software, just remove them, and instead import the Firebase libraries using whatever your bundler prefers.

Comment: Ahhh. So if I'm using firebase hosting AND a bundler, I can use `npm i firebase` to achieve the same effect? Never thought to look for the [firebase npm package before.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase). Do you think it's possible to use the emulators with a non-firebase localhost?

Comment: Okay great. [here are instructions on using firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase#npm-bundler-browserify-webpack-etc) with Browserify specifically on the NPM package page. The firebase functionality can even be used in the same modular way by only installing the functionality that is needed.